# Find MIN value that is > 0, also no negative values

Tags: mysql

I want to read a line from MySQL that gives me back averages, std dev pop and max as well as mins.

Basically, I want to get MINs from a specific table, but not 0, or anything less than 0.

I tried

```
MIN(NULLIF(`stock_qty`, 0)) AS `stock_qty`,
```

as a SELECT-param, but that has only returned null if MIN is 0

My current approach looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(`stock_qty`) AS `stock_qty_max`,
    MIN(`stock_qty`) AS `stock_qty_min`,
    AVG(`stock_qty`) AS `stock_qty_avg`,
    STDDEV_POP(`stock_qty`) AS `stock_qty_std`,
    SUM(`stock_qty`) AS `stock_qty_sum`,
    MAX(`adjusted_online_set`) AS `adjusted_online_set_max`,
    MIN(`adjusted_online_set`) AS `adjusted_online_set_min`,
    AVG(`adjusted_online_set`) AS `adjusted_online_set_avg`,
    STDDEV_POP(`adjusted_online_set`) AS `adjusted_online_set_std`,
    SUM(`adjusted_online_set`) AS `adjusted_online_set_sum`,
    COUNT(*) AS `count`
FROM
    `cat_product` AS `prod`
        LEFT JOIN
    `cat_position` AS `pos` ON pos.product_id = prod.product_id
        RIGHT JOIN
    `cat_product_website` AS `pweb` ON pos.product_id = pweb.product_id
WHERE
    (pos.category_id = '8476')
    AND ((prod.adjusted_online_set > 0) OR (prod.stock_qty > 0))
```

But this is also returning negative values for both fields.

Comment: I edited it a minute before your comment. :)

Comment: Using a subquery should do what you need..   `(SELECT MIN(stock_qty) FROM  ... WHERE stock_qty > 0) AS stock_qty`

Comment: *"I edited it a minute before your comment. :) "* i know i saw the edit still the question is limitted in information.. As we need to have example data and expected results to give solid answers.. Without we are just geussing as SQL is a declarative language..

Comment: Actually your comment was right - if you comment it as solution I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

min(
CASE
    WHEN `stock_qty` > 0 THEN `stock_qty`
    ELSE NULL
END
) AS `stock_qty`